# Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object ... in SQL SERVER SP PHP

Tags: php, stored-procedures

I am having problems in connecting my SQL SERVER stored procedure into my PHP forms... it tells me an error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object ...

please help im new in SQL SERVER STORED PROCEDURE

MY PHP CODE:

```
<?php

$serverName = " BONGBONG-PC ";  
$connection = array( "Database"=>"benefit_insurance"); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connection); 


$btn=$_POST['button']; 
$fname = $_POST['fname']; 
$lname=$_POST['lname']; 


TRY{
    if($btn=='LOGIN'){ 

        $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare ($conn,'CALL insert_record(@fname, @lname)'); 
        if( !$stmt ) { 
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
        } 



        $stmt->execute(array( 
            '@fname' => $fname, 
            '@lname' => $lname, 
        )); 

        echo "<script language=javascript>alert('ACCOUNT SAVED')</script>";

    }
} 


catch (PDOException $e) { 
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>"; 
    die();
} 
?>
```

Comment: on which line are you getting this error..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not in the stored procedure.
You use resource as an object. It is not correct.

And there is no reason to use prepare statements for only one query.

You need next code:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query ($conn,'EXECUTE insert_record @fname = ?, @lname = ?', array($fname, $lname)); 
if( $stmt === false ) { 
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
}
```

Comment: i tried it but i get this error  Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. ) )

Comment: Were you able to compile/run your stored procedure from SSMS directly?
Provide us your SQL-code

Comment: Maybe it will be better if you `EXEC` your procedure instead of `CALL`?
Try to use `EXEC insert_record @fname = ?, @lname = ?`

Comment: tnx a lot sir... i managed to solve the errors in my php but as i click the button it tells successfully save but when i look into the table theres no data inserted... i guess my SP is wrong